# Function dplyr::tally() not sorting with data.table and dtplyr

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I'm trying the new package `dtplyr` and some code that was already running broke (actually without it, other things fail, yet I haven't find a reproducible example of that). I'm trying to sort a summarized `data.table` and is failing.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
library(dtplyr)
library(dplyr)

data.table(category = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a')) %>%
group_by(category) %>%
tally(sort = T)
```

which yields:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "desc"
```

The strange thing is that if I comment out the package `dtplyr` or remove the parameter `sort = T` from `tally`, it works.

Running `R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)` on `Ubuntu 16.04`

Any suggestions?

Ps. Couldn't create the `dtplyr` tag, not enough reputation.

Comment: You can file a bug with the package: https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr The code runs fine for me if only data.table and dplyr are loaded, but I see the same error as you otherwise.

Comment: Possibly order of loading packages? Maybe try loading `dplyr` before `dtplyr`?

Comment: In the meantime, replacing the `group_by` and `tally` with `count` yields the same result.

Comment: Bug. If you call `arrange` afterwards, `desc` works fine.

Comment: Added the bug to [Github Repo](https://github.com/hadley/dtplyr/issues/33). Yet, no answer still.